# Count the number of occurrences of two characters in python column

Tags: python, string, find-occurrences

I have a dataframe (df) with variable Area representing the Area code. I need to find the number of occurences for Z followed by X
In the following example Z->X is repeated twice which means count is 2

```
Area
Z
A
B
Z
X
A
B
Z
X
```

I have tried the following to find True/False

```
    df.Area.str.contains(r'Z|X')
```

I am sure that this is wrong approach as it didn't give me a desired result. Any other way of doing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `shift()` function, specify the `period` parameter to be `-1` to shift the series one step forward, and this guarantees that `Z` is followed by `X`:

```
((df.Area == "Z") & (df.Area.shift(-1) == "X")).sum()
# 2
```

A closer look at how `shift` works:

```
df["Area_shift"] = df.Area.shift(-1)

df
#  Area  Area_shift
# 0   Z           A
# 1   A           B
# 2   B           Z
# 3   Z           X
# 4   X           A
# 5   A           B
# 6   B           Z
# 7   Z           X
# 8   X         NaN
```

Comment: This is really helpful!! Thank you